# How to replace popup in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I made a chrome extension and now I have two versions of my popup folders side to side in two languages. They both contain `popup.html, popup.css and popup.js`. The question is, how do I get them to swap on user input? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup

Comment: @wOxxOm
Thanks again! Sorry for such non-trivial questions, I almost finished the project and I wanna see the result as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.